# D3 Scatterplot legend overlapping

Tags: d3.js, legend

I have a scatterplot that works fine, but the legend I add to it is overlapping the chart. My current approach is to make the chart DIV be 70% of the width and have the legend take up the remaining 30%. For some reason, the legend isn't showing up on the screen, even though the HTML is there.

This is the link to my initial problem: http://jsfiddle.net/chp5a09e/373/

Here is the link to what I'm currently trying: http://jsfiddle.net/chp5a09e/372/

```
var legend = d3.select("#legend").append("svg")
    .attr("width", $("#legend").width())
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  legend.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(color.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
    });

  legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", width - 12)
    .attr("width", 12)
    .attr("height", 12)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d);
    })
    .on("click", function(d) {
      d3.selectAll(".symbol").style("opacity", 1)

      if (clicked !== d) {
        d3.selectAll(".symbol")
          .filter(function(e) {
            return e.items[columns.indexOf("Channel")] !== d;
          })
          .style("opacity", 0.1)
        clicked = d
      } else {
        clicked = ""
      }
    });

  legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", width - 16)
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> HTML is there

Only group (g) elements are there, and they are never visible themselves. In your original code

```
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(color.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
    ...

  legend.append("rect")
```

the `legend` here is a selection of multiple `g.legend` elements, and thus a rect gets appended to each of them, as well as gets access to the datum bound to the parent g. However in you new code

```
var legend = d3.select("#legend").append("svg")
    ...
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  legend.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(color.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
    ...;

  legend.append("rect")
```

The `legend` here refers only to the single `g` element that contains your whole legend. Your `legend.selectAll(".legend")` isn't saved into variable, so while inside the chain you set class and transform attributes properly, you don't use it to get rect appended to it -- again, `legend` at that point refers to the outter single g container.

---

Potential solution:

```
var legendCnt = d3.select("#legend").append("svg")
    .attr("width", $("#legend").width())
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var legend = legendCnt.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(color.domain())
...
```

You'll notice you'll need to remove or lower x attribute for text and rect, since 0 is now at the beginning of the legend instead of chart

Comment: Hmm Ok, I see what you're saying, I think. Though I'm still a little unclear of how to fix it.

Comment: @cstreet edited, thought (not to be rude) you might be trying to bite too much too early if it stumped you. Make sure you get a strong grasp on the base (enter-merge-update-exit loop; select vs selectAll and nested data join, how call works)

Comment: Omg, I had done this approach earlier but completely forgot about adjusting the X attribute. Thanks for the help!